# Союзы И ИЛИ: семантика

Tags: семантика, союзы

1. "Выберите все желтые и зеленые предметы", означает выбрать из некоторого списка все предметы, которые **либо** желтые, **либо** зеленые (по умолчанию предполагаем, что предметы одноцветные).

Хотя **либо**-это союз **или**, а не **и**.
Никакой логики.

2. "Выберите все желтые и зеленые предметы", означает выбрать из некоторого списка все желтые, а также зеленые предметы (по умолчанию предполагаем, что предметы одноцветные).

Второй пример мне кажется логичным, а также интуитивно понятным.

Как правильно?

Comment: Зря Вы поменяли тире, поставленные мною, на дефис (без пробелов) — это _неверная_ пунктуация. Теперь у Вас появились новейшие, удивительнейшие слова: **предметы"-означает** и **либо-это**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно первое. Логика есть, где-то она обсуждалась, но попробую своими словами. Постановка вопроса выдает в вас математика, поэтому предельно формально.

Операция "И" в языке обычно применяется не к объектам, как в математических дисциплинах, а к свойствам или даже к действию.

Если провести операцию, подобную раскрытию скобок, то фраза будет звучать примерно так:

**Выберите все желтые и выберите все зеленые предметы**.

Или того более:
**Выберите все предметы, являющиеся желтыми, и все предметы, являющиеся зелеными.**

Согласитесь, что замена на "либо" или "или" в обоих случаях тут порождает совершенно другой результат.

Забавно, но это понимание естественного языка прослеживается не только в русском, возможно это общее свойство бытового человеческого мышления.
А вот математикам приходится быть более формальными, поэтому там значение союзов (представленных там как кванторы и операторы) действительно таково, как вы написали.
//==
Забавно, что обычно-то просты смертные, увидев математический подход, как раз и говорят "никакой логики". )))

Comment: Я не математик, это то и пугает. Уточните, пожалуйста.
"Выберите все желтые и выберите все зеленые предметы."
Ну то есть если первый вариант правильный, то значит, нужно выбрать из двух одно. Тогда смысл "Выберите все желтые или выберите все зеленые" остается таким же что и в первом варианте, я не вижу разницы о.о

Выберите все желтые и выберите все зеленые предметы.
Одно не отрицает другое, разве нет? То есть союз и здесь как знак плюс. Если не ошибаюсь в логике, союзу и приравнивается знак +
(+ (зеленые) (желтые)), хотя в таком случае получится (салатовый) а должно (зеленые, желтые)

Comment: @dkha *Ну то есть если первый вариант правильный, то значит, нужно выбрать из двух одно* - вы сами запутались. Вы же в первом варианте так и написали, что те, которые либо зеленые, либо желтые. - то есть и то, и другое.

Comment: @dkha *"Выберите все желтые или выберите все зеленые" остается таким же что и в первом варианте* - да нет же, ну посмотрите, у вас в первом варинте и то, и другое выбирается.

Comment: По всей видимости, да, я запутался. Союз либо воспринимается, как то, что исключает, первое. Еду в Москву, либо в Санкт-Петербург. Не еду же я в оба города сразу.

Comment: Вы можете выбрать все командировки, которые либо в Москву, либо в Петербург. Ездить будете поочерёдно в каждую: предметы, которые оказывались при переборе либо зелёными, либо жёлтыми, вы складывали или отмечали тоже поочерёдно.

Comment: @Alex_ander Тогда чем отличается. Еду в Москву и в Санкт-Петербург. Неужели только в порядке очередности.

Вот два примера:
"Возьмите все деньги и паспорт"
"Возьмите все деньги или паспорт"
В первом случае я положу в сумку паспорт, деньги.
Во втором случае я возьму, например, только паспорт.

Comment: @dkha Ваши примеры не совсем корректны в данном контексте. Чтобы объяснить, я чуть переформулирую: "Откройте ящичек стола и возьмите оттуда все предметы, которые являются или деньгами, или документами" (коротко говоря: "всё, что или деньги, или документы"). Уверен, что Вы возьмёте правильно.

Answer (score 0):

Попытаюсь объяснить как математик нематематику.
(Upd.: В итоге я повторил предыдущий ответ, но другими словами — оставлю, вдруг так будет понятнее.)

> "Выберите все желтые и зеленые предметы"-означает выбрать из
>   некоторого списка все желтые, а также зеленые предметы (по умолчанию
>   предполагаем, что предметы одноцветные).

Высказывание "Выберите все желтые и зеленые предметы" содержит двусмысленность. Его можно понять так: нужно выбрать все предметы, которые одновременно являются и жёлтыми, и зелёными. Или так: нужно выбрать все жёлтые предметы и все зелёные предметы.

Пояснение "означает выбрать из некоторого списка все желтые, а также зеленые предметы" этой двусмысленности не снимает. И как Вы верно заметили, требуется дополнительный контекст. Вы даёте его так: "по умолчанию считаем, что все предметы одноцветные". Вот только этого контекста мало: если я не выберу ни одного предмета, то я буду по-своему прав. Контекст нужен не столько относительно предметов, сколько относительно самого указания.

Чтобы Вариант 2 звучал корректно, его нужно исправить: **выберите все жёлтые и все зелёные предметы**. Я уверен, что эту фразу все поймут однозначно. (Ключевой момент здесь — повторяющееся "все".)

Пояснение в Варианте 1 сразу снимает двусмысленность. "**Выбрать из некоторого списка все предметы, которые либо желтые, либо зеленые**" означает следующее: вы рассматриваете каждый предмет, и если он оказывается или жёлтым, или зелёным, то вы его выбираете. Обратите внимание, что высказывание "выберите или все жёлтые, или все зелёные предметы" имеет совершенно другой смысл. И с точки зрения математики (точнее, логики), и с точки зрения русского языка смысл здесь зависит от порядка, в котором употреблены слова "все" и "или".

Ещё раз в терминах логики: **Все (А или Б) = (Все А) и (Все Б)**.

Comment: ИЛИ, ЛИБО это синонимы, как они могут менять смысл при замене, для меня загадка.
"В Москву или в Саратов." = "В Москву либо Саратов."
Вы скажите с учетом всего сказанного, в итоге, что выберете, если скажут "Выберите все желтые предметы и все зеленые предметы" 
Просто, я повторюсь, загвоздка у меня в этом возникла, так как встретил, вариант, который, к моему удивлению, оказался популярнее, когда выбирают только желтые предметы или только зеленые, но не все вместе. Кстати, никто так и не ответил.

Comment: Кажется я понял проблему, с ИЛИ.
"Неоднозначность естественного языка заключается в том, что союз «или» используется в двух значениях: то для обозначения дизъюнкции, то для другой операции — строгой дизъюнкции (исключающего «ИЛИ»)."
Осталось И.

Comment: Вот про И, но не совсем то.
"Отличие логики естественного языка от математической остроумно выразил американский математик Стивен Клини, заметив, что в естественном языке «Мэри вышла замуж и родила ребенка» — не то же самое, что «Мэри родила ребенка и вышла замуж»."

Comment: 1) ИЛИ и ЛИБО это синонимы. Они не меняют смысл при замене. 2) Я выберу все предметы: и те, и другие. 4) Удивляюсь, как Вы не видите ответов. 3) Неоднозначность у союза ИЛИ действительно имеется, но в данном обсуждении она никак не проявляется. Здесь просто обсуждается, чем правильный вариант (вариант 1) разъяснения отличается от неправильного (вариант 2).

Comment: @dkha По поводу союзов Вы говорите правильно и приводите хорошие цитаты, просто это не имеет отношения к данной теме.

Comment: Ладно, закроем эту тему, я Вас не понимаю, Вы меня. Я почти уже разобрался.